# Django InconsistentMigrationHistory when adding app initial migration

Tags: django, django-migrations

[edit] solution found, details below

There are some interesting suggestions in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089173/django-inconsistentmigrationhistory-migration-x-is-applied-before-its-dependenc) but it doesn't help with my problem. Also, I have this app in production in several countries.

We are migrating an app and started with `managed=False` on all models. We then had a `claim_batch` app that has a migration `0002_capitationpayment`:

```
    dependencies = [
        ('product', '__first__'),
        ('claim_batch', '0001_initial'),
    ]
    # Some models with foreign keys to "product.Product"
```

The `product` module doesn't have migrations but it has models. When I do a `showmigrations` in this situation, I have:

```
  product
    (no migrations)
```

And it works fine somehow.

The problem is that I now need to add migration with a managed table in `product`. When I do the `makemigrations` and try to `migrate`, I'm getting:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration claim_batch.0002_capitationpayment is applied before its dependency product.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

It makes sense. The claim_batch.0002 is referencing a migration that is now existing but was not applied and it should not be possible to apply it after its dependency. Except in this scenario.

If I try to remove the dependency from the already applied migration, I'm getting:

```
ValueError: The field claim_batch.CapitationPayment.product was declared with a lazy reference to 'product.product', but app 'product' isn't installed.
```

I'm guessing that a clean install with this would work fine but I have production systems in various countries running in this state. Starting from scratch is not really an option.

[EDIT]
I can get it to work by manually adding the initial migration of the product app into the `django_migrations` table. It's not the best solution but it's manageable.