# django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration is applied before its dependency accounts.0001_initial on database 'default'

Tags: python, django, django-models, deployment, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to migrate my custom user model and I run `makemigrations` command to make migrations for new models. But when I run migrate command it throws this error :

> django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency accounts.0001_initial on database 'default'.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotesrow\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotesrow\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotesrow\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotesrow\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotesrow\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotesrow\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 95, in handle
    executor.loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\envs\dotesrow\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 302, in check_consistent_history
    raise InconsistentMigrationHistory(
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency accounts.0001_initial on database 
'default'.
```

**models.py**

```
class User(auth.models.AbstractUser):

    current_balance = models.IntegerField(("current balance"),default=0,blank=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(("age"),null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(("gender"), max_length=50,choices=GENDER_CHOICES,null=True)
    nationality = models.CharField(("nationality"), max_length=50,null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)
```

I just mentioned user model in this question but still if more code is require then tell me I'll update my question with that information . Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a version control tool such as git, just revert changes in migrations. But if not, you may clear migration history as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56535643/9070016).

It suggests to connect to database using `python manage.py dbshell` and then view migration history using `select * from django_migrations where app='admin';`.
Then find the id of 0001 migration and delete it like this: `delete from django_migrations where id=<some_id>;` where `some_id` is the migration id.

Answer (score -1):

django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency authentication.0001_initial on database 'default'.

1. DROP database
2. CREATE database
3. GRANT database
4. DELETE all migrations folder
5. MIGRATIONS
6. MIGRATE

Answer (score -2):

delete all the Migration folders. **also** delete db.sqlite3, then run `python manage.py makemigrations` *and* `python manage.py migrate`